# as.date function returns NA values from google.finance time series (eg. 19-01-17)

Tags: r, as.date

I've got this dataframe from google.finance and I want the "Date" column to be in date format.

```
`read.csv("ual.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)?
 head(Ual_df)
       Date  Open  High   Low Close  Volume
1 19-May-17 76.42 78.34 76.18 77.98 4143616
2 18-May-17 76.32 77.18 75.62 75.98 3559591
3 17-May-17 78.06 78.63 75.94 76.18 5673018`
```

As you can see, the dates are a bit ambiguous, since the days and the years are in the same format. 
I did this:

```
Ual_df$Date <- as.Date(Ual_df$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

and it returned NAs.

```
  head(Ual_df)
  Date  Open  High   Low Close  Volume
1 <NA> 76.42 78.34 76.18 77.98 4143616
2 <NA> 76.32 77.18 75.62 75.98 3559591
3 <NA> 78.06 78.63 75.94 76.18 5673018
```

I also tried to set the C locale but nothing changed.

Any suggestions ? Thank you.

Comment: That is because the named months are not defined by `%m`. See `?strptime` for more info

Comment: `as.Date("17-May-17", "%d-%b-%y")` (oops there is already an answer... sorry @akrun)

Comment: @amatsuo_net IMHO and with greater respect, it is fine.

Comment: @amatsuo_net You DO NOT need to apologise! My comment was already there while I was looking for a dupe.

Comment: Try as.Date.numeric

Comment: @Sotos. Problem solved. I didn't think that %m was the issue. I am new with R and this kind of problems. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

We need `%b` and the order should be changed

```
Ual_df$Date <- as.Date(Ual_df$Date, "%d-%b-%y")
Ual_df$Date
#[1] "2017-05-19" "2017-05-18" "2017-05-17"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lubridate` package is best for dealing with dates.  The following will even work if your `Ual_df$Date` column is a factor:

```
library(lubridate)
Ual_df$Date = dmy(Ual_df$Date)
```